# tool / API for extracting football matches result to automatically insert into database

Tags: hana, sap-business-technology-platform

I have HANA database on SAP Neo Cloud Platform for storing results of Football events (matches of Euro, World Cup, Championship League, Premier Leagues).

Each Cup type has its own table (one for Euro, one for World Cup ... ), in which I store results of all seasons (example, Euro 2020, 2016, 2012 ...).

As there are much data coming almost every day I need an automatic way for inserting new rows with results, which will be done on Live or every day at the same time.

Is there a tool, which will extract data and generate inserts for database and which I can deploy to SAP Cloud Platform for automatic processing or Open WebService/Database, with which I can work comfortably to automatically do it myself?

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data source (OData service, SOAP service, ...) you could simply use [Smart Data Integration](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/06/22/smart-data-integration-available-for-hcp/) for SAP Cloud Platform to get the data into your database.

Comment: Can I connect to REST service as Data Source?

Answer (score 0):

you can use an api that give you all the matches real time

check out this one

https://rapidapi.com/hmoccupe/api/sports-scores

Answer (score 0):

We are a provider of betting website solutions in Korea. All you need is a stable API or websocket real-time data without a web UI.

Real-time and pre-match API data such as country, league, match, team, market (how to play), and odds are required.

The data should have game results (statistics and live animation). Live data should have low latency, live data should have at least
Soccer, basketball, volleyball, baseball, ice hockey, etc. It is good if there are many sports.

You must provide a testable API and quote.

The request frequency (qps) is relatively high. It is best to pay monthly and not limit the frequency of requests.